# Error when using Connect-MsolService username and password

Tags: powershell, azure

Why I get this error when trying to use this command Connect-MsolService

```
Connect-MsolService : The user name or password is incorrect. Verify your user name, and then type your 
password again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80048821,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
```

The user that I am trying to login with is a global admin.

Comment: I got this also when I tried a user tied to a Microsoft Account.  If you use something like 'administrator@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com', you should be able to get connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add your credential object to the cmdlet, because it does not do native passthrough if your currently logged in user.

For example Connect-MSOLOnline -Credential (Get-credential)

Comment: I did not understand what you mean and I still get the same error with the code you provided.

Comment: Here are my notes from my work notebook on connecting to MSOL. Follow these instructions
 https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn975125.aspx
Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules and delete MSOnlineExtended (Duplicate Commands)
Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/10/23/getting-started-with-azure-active-directory/
Connect to MSOL
$cred = Get-Credential #Credential must be email address and AD password
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred